# Locale for Norwegian, Bokmal(Norway) issue

Tags: java, windows, servlets, locale, number-formatting

*I am facing problem while opening a downloaded CSV file in Excel under window 7 for above locale. Sometime the number is treated as date and all the cells are misaligned and formatted incorrectly.*

I have written code for CSV download with the localized format. It's working perfectly for all the regions except this one.

I invested the issue and it came to know that there is a mismatch between format defined on Windows 7 system and locale retrieved from [ServletRequest#getLocale()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29) for **Norwegian, Bokmal(Norway)**.

Here is my code:

Servlet:

```
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter=(DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);

locale.getDisplayCountry();            // empty string
decimalFormatter.toLocalizedPattern(); // #,##0.###
locale.getDisplayLanguage();           // Norwegian Bokmål
locale.toString();                     // nb
```

Now look at the **Digit grouping symbol** and **Decimal symbol** in above code.

---

**My Question:** How can I get the correct number format pattern as it is on Windows 7?

Here is the screenshot of the Languages set in Firefox.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of Language and Region on Windows 7 where for numbers **Digit grouping symbol** is a single space and **Decimal symbol** is a comma.

[image]

Comment: If you want it to be correct for Norwegian, the single space and decimal comma is correct

Comment: What does `decimalFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()` and `decimalFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()` return ? The `toLocalizedPattern()` is only one part of how decimals are formatted, the symbols are the other part.

Comment: @nos It's same the result with your suggestion. :( How can I get the correct number format for **Norwegian, Bokmal(Norway)**?

Comment: @nos Let me check it again. Yes the issue is with Excel opening a CSV file but that can be solved if CSV is correctly formatted based on client system's locale.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6.0_23

Comment: Using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45 for Windows, I get the same results as @Tobb below.

Comment: @haraldK how did you try it? I am talking about a web application in Servlet. Look at my another post [different locale pattern on standalone Java application and Web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613071/different-locale-pattern-on-standalone-java-application-and-web-application)

Answer (score 3):

The language of the decimal format should work straight "out of the box".

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("nb");
    DecimalFormat decimalFormatter=(DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);

    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry());           
    System.out.println(decimalFormatter.toLocalizedPattern()); 
    System.out.println(decimalFormatter.toLocalizedPattern()); 
    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage());        

    System.out.println(decimalFormatter.format(1234.567));
```

Yields this result for me:

```
(empty)
# ##0,###
# ##0,###
Norwegian Bokmål
1 234,567
```

The decimal format is not controlled by the windows settings though, tried changing decimal separator to `.` in windows, with no effect.

Comment: Thanks but my issue is opening a csv file under windows 7 with the mentioned locale. I have updated my post.

Comment: I know that decimal format is not controlled by the windows settings that's why I have pasted screenshot of Firefox Language preferences from where it is derived.

Comment: If you try it in Servlet then you will get the different result as shown in my post. May be you have tried it as standalone JAVA application.

Comment: Look at my another post [different locale pattern on standalone Java application and Web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613071/different-locale-pattern-on-standalone-java-application-and-web-application).

Comment: I have only tried it as a unit-test, but it shouldn't be any different. The outputs in your question with regards to the properties of the locale shows that it's the "nb" locale, whether it's obtained from a servlet context or just created shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Tobb The locale is created (`new`), so it will be the same, however, the `DecimalFormat/NumberFormat` are looked up, so they could be different, if the server provides its own implementations.