# different locale pattern on standalone Java application and Web application

Tags: java, servlets, locale, decimalformat

#### Why there is a different outputs for below code when tried as a standalone Java application and as a Web application (Servlet)?

**Code:**

```
Locale locale=new java.util.Locale("nb");// locale for Norwegian, Bokmal (Norway)
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter=(DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);

System.out.println(decimalFormatter.toLocalizedPattern());
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
System.out.println(decimalFormatter.format(1234.567));
```

Outputs:

#### standalone JAVA application:

```
# ##0,###
Norwegian Bokmål
1 234,567
```

#### as a WEB application (Servlet)

```
#,##0.###
Norwegian Bokmål
1,234.567
```

`Java Version  : JDK.1.6.0_23
 Web Server    : Jetty enclosed in Eclipse Juno`

---

**EDIT**

Here is the some findings as suggested by @haraldK

#### Is it possible to get the NumberFormat as provided by standard Java implementation rather than provider implementation?

Here is the source code of [NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/NumberFormat.java#NumberFormat.getInstance%28%29) that internally calls private method [NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale,int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/NumberFormat.java#NumberFormat.getInstance%28java.util.Locale%2Cint%29) as shown below:

```
private static NumberFormat getInstance(Locale desiredLocale,
                                       int choice) {
    // Check whether a provider can provide an implementation that's closer
    // to the requested locale than what the Java runtime itself can provide.
    LocaleServiceProviderPool pool =
        LocaleServiceProviderPool.getPool(NumberFormatProvider.class);
    if (pool.hasProviders()) {
        NumberFormat providersInstance = pool.getLocalizedObject(
                                NumberFormatGetter.INSTANCE,
                                desiredLocale,
                                choice);
        if (providersInstance != null) {
            return providersInstance;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am investing [Locale for Norwegian, Bokmal(Norway) issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610651/locale-for-norwegian-bokmalnorway-issue).

Comment: If you look at `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale, int)` (private method), you'll see that it uses a service provider mechanism to find implementations matching the locale. It could be that the app server you are using provides its own, that overrides the default implementation. Your question should be updated with Java version and application server and version.

Comment: @haraldK **Can I stop picking it from provider's implementation?** I need standard format always as provided by JAVA itself.

Comment: Check for `NumberFormatProvider` implementations in your class path, and see if you can remove them (their JARs). Otherwise, you could provide your own implementation that overrides the one that interferes and re-instates the default behavior. But I'm on thin ice now.. ;-)